# Simplifying and expanding $8 \sin^2(3 \theta)-4$

Tags: trigonometry

> Simplify and expand $$8 \sin^2(3 \theta)-4$$

I'm stuck on this question can someone help me and show solution.

Comment: Is the edit correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Sorry, first time on this site.

Comment: "Simplify" is really subjective here.  Do you want the argument to be $\theta$ instead of $3\theta$?

Comment: I think my teacher wants it simplified using compound or double angle identities.

Answer (score 1):

Using $\cos(2x)=\cos^2x-\sin^2x=1-2\sin^2x$, we can see that this expression is
$$8\sin^2(3\theta)-4=-4\cdot(1-2\sin^2(3\theta))=-4\,\cos(6\theta)\,.$$